# Proxy error on android 6 device with ionic 4 app

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-webview, capacitor

I am getting the following error (see image) when running a very basic Ionic 4 / Capacitor app on an Android 6 device.

I think it is because the the Android system webview needs to be updated.
I don't have access to the device myself as it is with a client, all I have is an emulator.  I can't seem to update the webview version on the emulator and I don't think this is possible so I can't replicate.

Capacitor states it should work with back to Android 5.1 if the webview is up to date.
I am not that familiar with older Android devices.

- **Is it as simple as sending this link and getting them to update the webview via the play store?**
  **Will the device have play store installed?**

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview&hl=en

[image]

Capacitor docs:
https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/android/
`**Note:**  Currently to use an Android Emulator you must use a system image of at least Android version 7.0 on API 24. This is due to the System WebView version not being able to be updated on emulators. Physical devices should work as low as Android 5.1 so long as they are kept updated.`

**Update:**

I go the app to run on the device by removing all Capacitor plugins.
How ever I still have several issues:

- I need to use plugins in the app
- The css is not getting displayed correctly at all.  None of the Ionic 4 colors are applying and the style are off.

It appears even after updating the Android system webview via google play to the latest and updating google chrome it is still using an old version of the webview.
Here is the userAgent output:

```
Mozilla/5.0(Linux; Android 6.0; C72 Build/MRA58K; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/44.0.2403.119
Mobile Safari/537.36
```

The latest version on chrome is 73.0.3683.90 so it is way off.
This is the device:
https://www.chainway.net/Products/Info/42

**Final Update:**

I contacted the manufacturer of the device and they confirmed that the webview was locked to version 44 on the firmware.
They are look at providing an updated version of the firmware with a more recent webview version.

Also it was only the capacitor/core plugins that were not working.  I could still use other 3rd party plugins such as a barcode reader.

If you are in the situation above I recommend using navigator.userAgent to determine the webview version as mentioned by @jcesarmobile in the comments below.

Comment: It looks like other people are having issues too and it is to do with the Capacitor Plugins.  I have removed these for now and will update with results.

https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/913
https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/1340
https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/1388

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you send that link and they update the Android System WebView then the app should work fine.

Unless your customer is in China, Play Store doesn't work there.

Comment: They have updated webview via the play store to the latest version (73.0.3683.90) and still have the error.  So no luck there.  Maybe I should try building it with Cordova?

Comment: What do they get if they run navigator.userAgent? I’ve heard some android devices don’t use the updatable webview. Would be good to know the device vendor and model if their userAgent shows an old chrome version despite having the webview updated

Comment: Do you have any idea how I could get this to run with the app?  Currently it just hits that error screen so I'm not sure how I would get it to run and display to the user.  I have removed all use of the Capacitor plugins so will see how that goes.  All I know about the device is that it is one of these: https://www.chainway.net/Products/Info/42

Comment: The proxy is required for plugins to work. So removing the plugins should fix it, but you will never be able to use plugins. BTW, that screen should only appear while in development, in production it will just not work

Comment: Yes I just got confirmation that it is working now with the Capacitor plugins removed.  Lucky for this project so far I don't need any plugins.  In theory it should work with plugins down to version 5.1 right?  I have another Capacitor project which needs to support Android 6 with plugins.

Comment: It should work on Android 5.0 and newer as long as they use the updatable webview and it's up to date, but some devices, for some reason are not using the updatable webview despite having Android 5 or newer.

Comment: I just got some screenshots back and it looks like the Ionic 4 styles are not applying properly either.  Primary Colour etc.  Client asking for Plugins now too.  Here is the userAgent: Mozilla/5.0(Linux; Android 6.0; C72 Build/MRA58K; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/44.0.2403.119
Mobile Safari/537.36  Any idea if I can upgrade the webview somehow?

Comment: You said they updated the webview already, but looks like that device is not using the system webview as it shows chrome 44 instead of 73, so I don't think there is something you can do.

Comment: Thanks for your help @jcesarmobile, your suggestions were very useful.  I am getting an update of the firmware from the manufacturer to resolve the issue.